# Grades ___ school subject

Tags: prepositions

Which variant is correct?

1. My grades *in* Geography are B, A+ and C.
2. My grades *from* Geography are B, A+ and C.
3. My grades *for* Geography are B, A+ and C.
4. My grades *of* Geography are B, A+ and C.
5. My grades *at* Geography are B, A+ and C.

Or something completely different?

Comment: Which one do you think is correct and why?

Comment: @David M, I think that the first one is correct but I don't have any idea why. It's only feeling. That's why i'm asking. I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: I just found out that there is a site for English Learners. I'm sorry for asking here but could you give me the answer here?

Comment: It's fine, we can simply migrate this question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a school subject is spoken of somewhat like a room: you are said to be "in" it, so your grades in that subject or room are B, A+ and C. (line 1)

An alternate expression is "taking" a subject ("I took web design 102 last semester.") which goes along with "getting" a grade ("I got a B, an A+ and a C."). This is similar to line 2.

Line 3 is not used as much as the previous examples, but is equally understandable and completely legitimate English.

Line 4 is not provably wrong, but doesn't "sound right". Its meaning is identical to the others and is usable English.

Line 5 also "doesn't sound right", but is similar to saying "My *skill* at geography is high", which is a normal sounding sentence.

I hope this isn't more confusing than clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

1 is preferred. 3 is correct, but doesn't sound quite as natural. 2,4 and 5 are completely wrong *sounding* although there may not be any actual *rule* to explain it.

Comment: @xxdavid  I appreciate you "accepting" my answer, but I see that you are new here. By "accepting" my answer (selecting the checkmark) you may discourage others from answering, or even reading, the question. Unless you are *sure* that you have received the best answer you can get, you probably want to hold off on that for at least a day or two. If you just just appreciate an answer (but want more if you can get them), then click the up arrow. That also gives points to the answerer, but doesn't call the question definitively answered.